# Cut specific words matching a pattern from a text file

Tags: shell, grep, cut

I am trying to extract words from a text file matching a pattern using shell script. For example if a line contains

```
This is a sample text to illustrate my scenario text=info id=2342
Second line to illustrate text=sample id=q2312
```

I want the output to be like

```
text=info id=2342
text=sample id=q2312
```

Can somone please tell me how do i achieve it using cut/grep command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following:

`grep -P -o 'text=\S+ id=\S+'`

The `-P` flag for `grep` enables the perl regular expression. `\S+` will match all non blank space characters, `-o` outputs only the matched portion.

Assuming you need to get the fields "text" and "id" values. Modify the regular expression as required. For perl regular expressions see [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) or extended regular expressions see `man grep`

Answer (score 2):

This `grep -oP` should work:

```
grep -oP '\b(\w+=\w+(\s+|$))+' file
text=info id=2342
text=sample id=q2312
```

Comment: Hi anubhava, this seems working for what mrezzaaa asked. But can you please a little bit explanatory about reg-ex used in grep.

Comment: `\w+` matches a word where `\b` is word boundary. `\w+=\w+` matches 2 words separated by `=` followed by `(\s+|$)` which 1+ space or end of line. `(\w+=\w+(\s+|$))+` will match multiple `name=value` pairs separated by space.

Answer (score 1):

With cut you need to process extra (cut from first = and add text=):

```
echo "text=$(echo "This is a sample text to illustrate my scenario text=info id=2342" | cut -d= -f2-)"
```

With sed:

```
echo "This is a sample text to illustrate my scenario text=info id=2342" | sed 's/.* text=/text=/'
```